# R using nested for loops and matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops

How to create a nested for loop in R?

how to find the correct values ​​in a matrix using a nested loop and store the values ​​in another matrix.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

**SYNTAX:**

```
for(i in 1:dim(mymat)[1]) {
  for(j in 1:dim(mymat)[2]) {
    
    if ( condition ) {
        # operations . . . 
    } else {
        # operations . . .
    }
  }
}
```

---

**An example:**

```
mymat <- matrix(nrow=30, ncol=30)
mymat2 <- matrix(nrow=30, ncol=30)

for(i in 1:dim(mymat)[1]) {
  for(j in 1:dim(mymat)[2]) {
    mymat[i,j] = i*j
    if (mymat[i,j]**2 - 10*mymat[i,j] + 10> 0) {
        mymat2[i, j] = i*j
    } else {
        mymat2[i, j] = -i*j
    }
  }
}

 mymat[1:10, 1:10]
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 #[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
 #[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20
 #[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30
 #[4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40
 #[5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50
 #[6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54    60
 #[7,]    7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63    70
 #[8,]    8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72    80
 #[9,]    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81    90
#[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100



 mymat2[1:10, 1:10]
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 #[1,]    1   -2   -3   -4   -5   -6   -7   -8    9    10
 #[2,]   -2   -4   -6   -8   10   12   14   16   18    20
 #[3,]   -3   -6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30
 #[4,]   -4   -8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40
 #[5,]   -5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50
 #[6,]   -6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54    60
 #[7,]   -7   14   21   28   35   42   49   56   63    70
 #[8,]   -8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72    80
 #[9,]    9   18   27   36   45   54   63   72   81    90
#[10,]   10   20   30   40   50   60   70   80   90   100
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot for the help, this gives an understanding of the solution.